# Where is using @ before a date string for seconds since the epoch documented?

Tags: date, documentation, gnu, coreutils

GNU `date` and `touch` commands (and presumably others) use `@date` to define a date string as seconds since the epoch. For example:

```
$ TZ=UTC date -d@10
Thu Jan  1 00:00:10 UTC 1970
```

I was answering a question and wanted to point the OP to where this particular feature was documented but I can't find it. Neither `man date` not `man touch` explain it. The closest is this from the "Examples" section of the `date` man page:

```
   Convert seconds since the epoch (1970-01-01 UTC) to a date

          $ date --date='@2147483647'
```

The `info` page for `date` states that this was introduced in `coreutils` 5.3.0, but does not really explain it further either:

```
 Or if you do not mind depending on the `@' feature present since
 coreutils 5.3.0, you could shorten this to:

      date -d @946684800 +"%F %T %z"
      1999-12-31 19:00:00 -0500
```

So, where is `@seconds` documented? Where am I supposed to learn about it and where can I point someone who does not? Is that off-hand mention in `man date` really the best we have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented in Section 28.9, "Seconds since the Epoch" of the `GNU Coreutils` info page:

```
info Coreutils 'Seconds since the Epoch'
```

I am including the first paragraph here: The section reads:

> If you precede a number with `@', it represents an internal time stamp
>   as a count of seconds.  The number can contain an internal decimal
>   point (either  `.' or`,'); any excess precision not supported by the
>   internal representation  is truncated toward minus infinity.  Such a
>   number cannot be combined with  any other date item, as it specifies a
>   complete time stamp.

Comment: Are you sure the capital `Coreutils` is needed? It isn't on my LMDE (which is basically Debian testing) and it shouldn't be since the "correct" name is `coreutils` and not `Coreutils`. I am afraid that it might not work on other systems unless its not capitalized.

Comment: @terdon I've tested on various machines; on them, `info Coreutils` always works, but `info coreutils` sometimes gives an unrelated page. Have you tried with GNU Coreutils 8.23?

Comment: @terdon The man pages still give the version with a lowercase c, though it no longer works. I've reported a bug: [Debian bug 760861](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=760861). So, let's see what the developers say.